# css/html entire website container stuck on left, and expands badly in responsive

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, alignment

This is my website: `http://guillermo.comuv.com/`

i can't figure out why the website (the div that wraps the white part) is fixated on the left side and i end up with tons of empty black space on the right side - i had to create another div ("master") just to push it alittle from the left because i couldn't figure out why it was stuck on the left and not centered like it used to be.

```
    #master {

    margin-left:90px;
    text-align:center;


    }

    #wrapper {
    width: 900px;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    padding-top: 0px;
    padding-right: 30px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    padding-left: 30px;
overflow:hidden;
    }
```

Comment: Please read: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put margin: auto on your #wrapper, this should center things for you.

#wrapper{margin: 0 auto;}

Comment: No problem, I always enjoy assisting fellow developers.

Comment: thank you, your solution worked! , one more question if you alredy had the chance to look at it i am trying to make the logo image inside the "header" stick with the navigation bar ("menu") by that i mean i want them to be close to eachother no spaces and be stretched across the same width of the things below:   #menu {
 float: left;
 padding: 0;
 margin-top: 35px;
 margin-bottom: 0;
 width: auto;
 overflow: hidden;
}#header {
 overflow: hidden;
 width: 100%;
 text-align: right;
 padding-top: 35px;
 padding-bottom: 0px auto;
 margin-bottom: 0px auto;

}

Comment: I would not be able to help you adequately in the comment but I'd consider putting the two elements(menu and logo) in  their own separate divs, it will be easier to style that way.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
#master { 
    margin-left:90px
}
```

with

```
#master { 
    margin:0 auto;
    width: 1200px // example width
}
```

The width of the container should most probably be set to something fixed in this case, alternatively simply applying `text-align:center` might do the trick.

Answer (score -1):

Make a div that wraps around your entire content and in the CSS style use this for the div you made:

```
#yourbig div {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```